# Downloads files instead of opening them

Tags: php, apache, easyphp

I downloaded EasyPHP 14.1 VC9, and downloaded all of my files from my webhost (new computer). Now when going to any folder below the `data/localweb/` level just causes my browser to download the file instead of executing and opening it.

For example:

`data/localweb/index.php` works fine.

`data/localweb/somefolder/index.php` doesn't work.

No wordpress or any craziness, just vanilla PHP. Any PHP on the root folder works fine, but my server architecture is just folders off the root - any way to keep it and have PHP find ALL php files and execute them as long as they are under the root folder?

I have these lines in the Apache config:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml .pwml .php5 .php4 .php3 .php2 .php .inc

LoadModule php5_module "${path}/binaries/php/php_runningversion/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

OS: Win7 Home Premium 64bit

Answer (score 1):

*facepalm*

Let this be a lesson learned for everyone out there.

The key we should be looking for from now on is 'downloaded from webhost'.

My `somefolder/` contained an extra `.htaccess` that was from my webhost. Deleting it solved the problem.